# Как обернуть один блок в другой без потери событий?

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с задачей в которой необходимо обернуть существующий в DOM дереве DIV блок с содержимым в другой див, созданный посредством createElement.
Казалась бы всё очень просто, берём метод cloneNode и вперёд, но дело в том, что этот метод клонирует только атрибуты и инлайн события, а события назначенные через `addEventListener` или `onclick = callback` - нет.
Полагаю, вырезать все при помощи div.innerHTML тоже не пойдет.
Так вот, как обернуть этот самый див с сохранением навешенных на него и его дочерние элементы событиями?

Comment: Навешивайте события через делегат, тогда будет не важно, сколько раз Вы копируете элементы

Comment: Дело в том, что это в некотором роде модуль и подключаться он будет где угодна и когда угодно и делегирование не в помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
button.addEventListener("click",function(){
  let e = document.createElement("div");
  this.parentNode.insertBefore(e, this);
  e.appendChild(this);
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">click me</button>
```

Comment: Сей вариант подходит хорошо, но поддержка скудная... Полагаю, иначе никак?

Comment: что значит `но поддержка скудная` ?

Comment: @webDev_, `appendChild` вроде вставит обёртку в конец родителя, а не на место оборачиваемого элемента

Comment: @diraria обновил

Comment: @webDev_, ага, теперь всё правильно

Comment: @webDev_, да, что-то я затупил) Думаю, если бы я изначально в доки заглянул, то понял что appendChild перемещает существующий узел, столько раз использовал appendChild и не знал о таком серьезном нюансе. В любом случае, вы мне помогли. низкий поклон! Полагаю этот способ надежен и работает в любом браузере? Ну за исключением `let` разумеется

Comment: да, поддержка имеется во всех браузерах

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать метод [`before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/before) для вставки элемента-обёртки перед оборачиваемым элементом, а затем [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) для вставки оборачиваемого элемента в элемент-обёртку.

```js
function wrap(element) {
  let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  element.before(wrapper);
  return wrapper.appendChild(element);
}

document.getElementById('button_wrap').addEventListener('click', () => wrap(document.getElementById('child')));
document.getElementById('button_alert').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('click'));
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<p id="child">
  элемент для оборачивания, с <button id="button_alert">кнопкой</button>, на которую навешан обработчик
</p>
<p>
  <button id="button_wrap">обернуть</button>
</p>
```